# Writing a list of matrices to csv?

Tags: r, list, matrix

how could I write a list of matrices into a csv file in R?

I tried

```
fff = tr[[3]]  
 MATweight = ldply(fff, function(t) t$toDataFrame())
```

but had this error

```
Error in t$toDataFrame : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I am not sure if it was the right thing to do, any idea please?

I have this list of matrices

```
    > str(fff)
    List of 10
     $ : num [1:1000, 1:50] 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
....
     $ : num [1:1000, 1:50] 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 ..
```

.

When I tried the suggested answer by G. I got:

```
 > write.csv(map_dfr(fff, as.data.frame, .id = "matrix"),"testt.csv",  row.names = FALSE)
    > tgtg = read.csv("/Users/amani/testt.csv")
    > str(tgtg)
    'data.frame':   10000 obs. of  51 variables:
     $ matrix: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ V1    : int  1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
     $ V2    : int  2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 ...
     $ V3    : int  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 ...
....
     $ V50   : int  2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
```

Comment: tr is a list of lists and the third list is a list of ten matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do it like this:

```
# sample data like your `fff` list of matrices
fff <- lapply(1:10, function(i) 
  matrix(data = sample(1:2, 510000, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10000, ncol = 51))


# we give each matrix in the list a unique name
mat_names <- as.character(1:length(fff))

# converting to dataframe with the list index preserved
fffdf <- lapply(1:length(fff), function(i)
  cbind(mat_names = mat_names[i], as.data.frame(fff[[i]])))
fffdf <- do.call(rbind, fffdf)

# writing it to a file
t <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
write.csv(fffdf, t, row.names = FALSE)

# testing the reassembly into the same list of matrices that you started
tcsv <- read.csv(t)
tgtg <- lapply(mat_names, function(i) {
  df <- subset(tcsv, mat_names == i, select = -mat_names)
  mat <- as.matrix(df)
  dimnames(mat) <- NULL
  return(mat)
})
```

Testing the result: is `tgtg` the same as the `fff` you began with?

```
> identical(fff, tgtg)
[1] TRUE

> str(tgtg)
List of 10
 $ : int [1:10000, 1:51] 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ : int [1:10000, 1:51] 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : int [1:10000, 1:51] 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ : int [1:10000, 1:51] 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ : int [1:10000, 1:51] 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ : int [1:10000, 1:51] 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ : int [1:10000, 1:51] 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ : int [1:10000, 1:51] 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ : int [1:10000, 1:51] 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ : int [1:10000, 1:51] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot J. Win. That did exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `L` test data shown, try `map_dfr` from purrr:

```
library(purrr)

L <- list(as.matrix(BOD), as.matrix(10*BOD)) # test data

write.csv(map_dfr(L, as.data.frame, .id = "matrix"), stdout(), row.names = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
"matrix","Time","demand"
"1",1,8.3
"1",2,10.3
"1",3,19
"1",4,16
"1",5,15.6
"1",7,19.8
"2",10,83
"2",20,103
"2",30,190
"2",40,160
"2",50,156
"2",70,198
```

Comment: Thank you G. Grothendieck! and sorry for the late reply. I tried this but the problem with it was,  it created a vector from each matrix!so, I don't have matrices any more just vectors of all the matrix's elements.  Is there any way to save this list as a list of matrices not a data frame of vectors?

Comment: As you can see from the output in the answer that is not the case.   If you have done something else or the question did not accurately describe the input or other aspects of the question then it's up to you to fix the question to ensure it is complete and reproducible.